# magicretry_fragment.xml: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/android:progressBarStyleSmall not found

Tags: android, androidx, payu

C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\f6772157844560351dc4ac406c6d9162\jetified-magicretry-1.0.6\res\layout-v11\magicretry_fragment.xml:121: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/android:progressBarStyleSmall not found.

I am using the following gradle dependency for payu sdk.

implementation "com.payu.india:payu-sdk:4.7.0"

I am facing this issue after migrating my project to androidx.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Should be `?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall`

Comment: But magicretry_fragment.xml is auto generated. How can I change this file? Please help me.